# Bluemix Push Notification service not working anymore?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

I have a native iOS Swift app talking to a `Node.js Bluemix` backend with MobileFirst services (AMA, Cloudant, Push iOS 8), which worked well for over a month. A few days ago I noticed that I could no longer register new devices from the iOS app **(IMFPushClient.sharedInstance().registerDeviceToken() responded with a 404).**

I knew that changes had been made recently to the MobileFirst services (**e.g.** the various push services were merged into one), so I figured I should rebind those services. This resolved the registration issue, but I haven't been able to receive push notifications ever since.

This is what I tried:

- **created** a completely new backend with the **"MobileFirst Services Starter"** boilerplate
- **cloned** the most recent version of the "**Bluelist**" sample app and **configured** it for this new backend
- **issued** a new **APNs** **certificate** for my bundle ID and uploaded it to the push service
- **successfully registered** for push notifications on my device. I have verified this by calling the /devices [REST API](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/) (essentially, I followed [these](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/index.html) steps).

Now every time I use the **REST API** to send messages (after figuring out that the bearer token approach was replaced with a new "appSecret" header), I get an **HTTP 202**, but the notification never arrives. Likewise, when I try to send the message through the service's dashboard, I get a success message, but the notification never arrives.

One thing I noted is that the symptoms stay the same even if I don't provide the .**p12** certificate to the service, so I wonder if this might be some certificate issue, but I have no idea how to trace this. Also, IIRC the "old" MobileFirst services required me to provide the bundle ID and version of the mobile app, but this seems to be gone now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am currently looking into this issue. Will let you know when I find out any further information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to solve the issue above by making sure the sandbox environment was using a sandbox .p12 file. To verify this setting go to the   **IBM Push Notification Dashboard** and click the **Configuration tab**:

[image]

Here you can see the Certificate Type of the .p12 file you have uploaded. Make sure if you are using the Sandbox environment it is listed as Sandbox. Same is true for the Production environment.

Comment: Note: There is a defect that is currently opened that requires the word "sandbox" in the .p12 certificate name for the sandbox environment. If your sandbox certificate is showing up as a production certificate please include the word sandbox in the certificate name. This will be fixed as soon as possible.