# Cannot push notification to iOS9 device

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Whenever I try to push a message to a registered device using the Push for iOS8 Bluemix dashboard, a message "The notification was sent." is displayed but my registered device never receives the notification.

According to the logs of my application, the device seems correctly registered to the Push for iOS8 service, and I'm also able to send push notifications to my device using https://github.com/nomad/houston (using the same certificate that I uploaded to the Push for iOS8 service, but converted to the .pem format).

My device is an iPad mini 4 running iOS 9.0.2.

Comment: My app's push notifications don't work on device's running IOS 9.0.2.  There is news that the 9.0.2 update breaks notifications.  I would like to know how and when it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was provided by the bluemix team: the name of the certificate uploaded for the sandbox needed to have "sandbox" in its file name (example: my-certificate-sandbox.p12). That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to test the push notifications.

[NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher)
[image]

Also check your device tokens, if you are getting them properly.

Above mentioned github link will help you to setup all.

Comment: I used https://github.com/nomad/houston to test and everything worked fine. The issue is definitely with the Bluemix push service.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of a previously answered question.
Please see the following:

[Bluemix Push Notification service not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013796/bluemix-push-notification-service-not-working-anymore/33102993#33102993)